# LNK2019 && LNK1120 errors when splitting my code in multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

My code is stored in a `main.cpp` file which contains the `void main()` function, and a class `MyClass` which I now want to split to another file. IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

`myclass.h`

```
#include <tchar.h>
class MyClass {
public:
    static bool MyFunction (TCHAR* someStringArgument);
};
```

`myclass.cpp`

```
#include <tchar.h>
class MyClass {
private:
    static bool someProperty;
    static void doSomeOneTimeCode () {
        if (!someProperty) {
            /* do something */
            someProperty = true;
        }
    }
public:
    static bool MyFunction (TCHAR* someStringArgument) {
        doSomeOneTimeCode();
        /* do something */
        return true;
    }
};
bool MyClass::someProperty = false;
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "myclass.h"
void main () {
    if (MyClass::MyFunction(TEXT("myString"))) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Yay\n"));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I get two linker errors.

- LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ... (mentions `MyClass::MyFunction`)
- LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

What can I do to prevent these linker errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared two classes here. One of them is in *myclass.h* and the other is in *myclass.cpp*.  Try the following instead:

### myclass.h

```
#ifndef myclass_h_included
#define myclass_h_included

#include <tchar.h>

class MyClass {
private:
    static bool someProperty;
    static void doSomeOneTimeCode ();
public:
    static bool MyFunction (TCHAR* someStringArgument);
};

#endif //!myclass_h_included
```

### myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

/*static*/ bool MyClass::someProperty = false;

void
MyClass::doSomeOneTimeCode() {
    //...
}
bool
MyClass::MyFunction(TCHAR* someStringArgument) {
    //...
}
```

Your *main.cpp* can stay the same.  I would pay attention to [UncleBens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549093/lnk2019-lnk1120-errors-when-splitting-my-code-in-multiple-files/1549128#1549128) reply as well.  One time initialization code should be hidden if at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yo can't split a class definition in parts. It must be defined as a whole in one place. If you want to just have some methods of the class defined create a interface class that the `MyClass` class will later inherit. You should put the class' definition in a header file (myclass.h) and it's implementation in a cpp file (myclass.cpp). That way you can include the "myclass.h" in your main cpp file and use the class in your main function (which should be `int main()` or `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`).

Comment: what speaks against `void main()` ?

Comment: The C and C++ Standards both explicitly call out `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` as two valid forms of `main` in a hosted environment.  Interestingly enough, C++ only requires that it is named `main` and it's return type is `int`... In any case, `void main()` is not allowed by either Standard.

Comment: ah okay, so visual studio permits `void main()` against the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Strange that you didn't get a compiler error, as you are redefining MyClass.

Definitions (implementations) go into the cpp, and they are defined like this:

```
#include "myclass.h"
//helper functions, particularly if static, don't need to be in the class
//unnamed namespace means this stuff is available only for this source file
namespace 
{
    bool someProperty;
    void doSomeOneTimeCode () {
        if (!someProperty) {
            /* do something */
            someProperty = true;
        }
    }
}

bool MyClass::MyFunction (TCHAR* someStringArgument) {
    doSomeOneTimeCode();
    /* do something */
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no compiler error because myclass.cpp does not include myclass.h

Comment: Ok. Added the include to show that the declaration of MyClass is still needed.